# One FusionTableLayer appears to be competing with another

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google map with two fusion table layers, one with markers and one with polygons. If I display both layers with no styling, they show up. If I style the markers, they both show up. BUT, when I try to style the polygons, the markers don't show up. I'm out of ideas.

```
// Initialize the first layer
    var firstLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: "'geometry'",
            from: '1eiyhdpl-5xnO7-csWgdrxxYHgFWRLjN0JADIX9o'
        },
        styles: [{
            where: "'ABORTIONS' < 100",
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#cc0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.2
            }
        },{
            where: "'ABORTIONS' > 100 AND 'ABORTIONS' < 1000",
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#cc0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.4
            }
        },{
            where: "'ABORTIONS' > 1000 AND 'ABORTIONS' < 10000",
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#cc0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.6
            }
        },{
            where: "'ABORTIONS' > 10000 AND 'ABORTIONS' < 100000",
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#cc0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.8
            }
        }],
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
    });

    // Initialize the second layer
        var secondLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
        select: "'address'",
            from: '1j7ogamqx3pXfiG0Eh1Ah0givle_thZE-OBgvQho'
        },
        styles: [{ 
        where: "rank = 1",
            markerOptions: {
            iconName: 'small_green'
           }
        },{ 
            where: "rank = 0",
                markerOptions: {
                    iconName: 'small_blue'
                }
        }],  
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
```

If I delete or comment the styles from firstlayer, the styled markers from secondlayer are there. They're just on top of the default red polygons from firstlayer. with the firstlayer styles, the markers from secondlayer disappear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can only style one FusionTablesLayer on a map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles

> Styles can only be applied to a single Fusion Tables layer per map. You may apply up to five styles to that layer.

Comment: You could use the FusionTables UI to style the two tables([Polygons](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2681556?hl=en), [Markers](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2679986?hl=en)) and not use the javascript styling (or only use it for one of the tables).

Comment: I will gladly do that. Noob question, how do I get those two fusion-styled maps to show up on the same map? All I've experienced is the default styles showing up regardless of how I style them in fusion tables. Thanks.

Comment: Just specify the `styleId` for each layer. [See the docs](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingStyles) for details.

Comment: Thanks Odi. Your suggestion led me to the Fusion Table Wizard which did everything I wanted and more!